# Remove Server from NGINX Plus Pool

Tags: nginx, cluster, deployment

Is it possible via a REST API or something to remove an Appserver from the Loadbalancer/NGINX Pool?

We have a problem in the deployment and would like to remove the appservers one by one and deploy the changes there. We could access NGINX Plus, but I could not find anything on their website.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way without root rights on the server to do so:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-reconfiguration-with-nginx-plus/

```
http://localhost:8080/upstream_conf?remove=&upstream=backend&id=2
```

With the following config changes:

```
location /upstream_conf {
        upstream_conf;      allow 10.0.0.0/8; # Allow access only from LAN
        deny all;         # Deny everyone else

    }


upstream backend {
    zone backend 64k;
    server 10.2.2.90:8000;
    server 10.2.2.91:8000;
    server 10.2.2.92:8000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The NGINX Plus web interface (see [demo](https://demo.nginx.com/status.html)) seems to be for live activity monitoring, only.

> [NGINX Plus extends](https://www.nginx.com/products/application-load-balancing/) the reverse proxy capabilities of the open
>   source NGINX software with an additional application load balancing
>   method, enhancements for multi-core servers, and features such as
>   session persistence, health checks, live activity monitoring, and
>   on-the-fly reconfiguration of load-balanced server groups.

The [NGINX Plus Configuration](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/configuration-files/) is done via configuration files, just like in the open-source NGINX.

> NGINX Plus is similar to other services in that it has a text-based
>   configuration file written in a particular format. By default the file
>   is named `nginx.conf` and placed in the `/etc/nginx` directory. (For the
>   open source NGINX product, the location depends on the package system
>   used to install NGINX and the operating system. It is typically one of
>   `/usr/local/nginx/conf`, `/etc/nginx`, or `/usr/local/etc/nginx`.)

The [Nginx Load Balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/) article describes how to use NGINX and NGINX Plus as a load balancer. In short, Nginx configuration file has this kind of section:

```
http {
    upstream backend {
        server backend1.example.com weight=5;
        server backend2.example.com;
        server 192.0.0.1 backup;
    }
}
```

Just comment out the backend servers you would like to disable and restart NGINX Plus.

Comment: We do not have Root rights to do so, but I found an article about that https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-reconfiguration-with-nginx-plus/

Comment: Nice, should work if enabled. I'll upvote your self-answer. :)